# Android open mail client

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I open mail client from my app, NOT SENDING EMAIL just open the inbox?
when I use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:recipient@example.com?subject=" + "" + "&body=" + "");
        intent.setData(data);
        startActivity(intent);
```

It opens the send mail view, and I want to open the inbox.

Comment: What if there are multiple mail clients on the users device? How will you decide which one to open?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From @CommonsWare answer

This is what worked for me:

```
Intent intent=Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//Min SDK 15
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: For me, it simply opens Gmail, but does not allow me to select from the installed email apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use in your xml, like this:

```
android:autoLink="email"
```